# Strange behavior with gcc inline assembly?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I'm new to gcc inline assembly.
Why this code output "1" instead of "5"?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static inline int atomic_add(volatile int *mem, int add)
{
    asm volatile(
            "lock xadd %0, (%1);"
            : "=a"(add)
            : "r"(mem), "a"(add)
            : "memory"
    );
    return add;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a=1;
    int b=5;
    printf ( "%d\n", atomic_add(&a, b) );
    return 0;
}
```

run:

```
$ ./a.out
1  # why not 5?
```

many thx. :)

Comment: Aside: have you considered using the atomics from C11?

Comment: thanks everyone. so, XADD means " Exchange and Add".

Comment: @Hurkyl thank you. I'm just curious about this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `add` stars out with the value 5 and `*mem` starts out with `1`.

The `lock xadd %0, (%1)` assembly template gets compiled by gcc to:

```
lock xadd %eax, (%edx)
```

GCC has to use `eax` because your constraints indicate that `%0` should use `%eax`.  Your constraint also ties `%eax` to the variable `add`.  I believe that GCC is free to us whatever register it wants for the other operand (in my test it happened to use `%edx`).

So:

- `%eax` starts with `5`, and `%edx` points to a memory location that has the value `1`
- the `xadd` instruction swaps the two operands and places the sum in the destination, so after executing `%eax` has `1` and `the memory pointed to by`%edx`contains`6`

  Your constraint also indicates that `%eax` should be stored back into the variable `add`, so `add` gets `1`.  And that is what is returned from the function.

Answer (score 2):

In x86, **XADD** is the [Exchange and Add](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_327.html) instruction. So the register holding the `add` parameter became `1` after the `lock xadd` instruction. `add` is then returned by `atomic_add()` thus you see `1` printed instead of `5`.

For `atomic_add()` you probably want to just use `lock add` instead of `lock xadd`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
static inline int atomic_add(volatile int *mem, int add)
{
    asm volatile(
            "lock add %0, (%1);"
            : "=a"(add)
            : "r"(mem), "a"(add)
            : "memory"
    );
    return add;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a=1;
    int b=5;
    printf ( "%d\n", atomic_add(&a, b) );
    return 0;
}
```

And this prints `5` like you expect:

```
$ ./a.out
5
```